# JAVA: How to enter an undefined number of values to a stringarray using a scanner?

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm new to Java and I'm making a program that can take a number of names and put them into an ArrayList and then print out the names. I would like the user to press ctrl-Z to indicate the end of the list. So far I have this:

```
    ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<>();
    System.out.print("Enter a name: ");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    name.add(in.next());
    in.nextLine().equals("");

    for(String naam: name){
        System.out.println(naam);
    }
```

But I think I need to do more with the for loop.

If anyone can give me a solution that would be great! But what would be even better if you could also explain what you have modified to get it working

Comment: How will `in.nextLine()` get more than 1 line, if it's not inside a loop?

Comment: You should call your list `names`, so you can use `name` as the for-each variable. It's usually clearer to use plurals for collections.

Comment: thanks for the tip! i have renamed my variables

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for **doing the loop**.

```
public class Scan {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean testContinue = true;

        while (testContinue) {

            System.out.println("Input a string :");
            String str = sc.next();

            if (str.equals("quit"))
                testContinue = false;
            else {
                /*
                 * add to arrayList
                 */
                arrayList.add(str);
                testContinue = sc.hasNextLine();
            }
        }

        /*
         * Display arrayList
         */
        for(int i = 0; i<arrayList.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(arrayList.get(i));
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example.  On Unix systems Control-z puts something in the background.  Did you mean control-d which usually means end of input?  If so, the following example will work.  The key is that control characters are not sent to you application but are interpreted by the terminal.  However, if you wrap System.in in a BufferedReader, then the BufferedReader will return null on EOF which will stop the scanner.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReadNames {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();

        System.out.print("Enter a name: ");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)));

        while( in.hasNext() ){
            String n = in.next();
            if( n.isEmpty() ){
                break;
            }
            names.add(n);
        }

        for(String name: names){
            System.out.println("Name: " + name);
        }
    }
}
```

Example run:

```
$ java ReadNames
Enter a name: dave
john
bill
<control-d here>
Name: dave
Name: john
Name: bill
```